# How to animate a text so it goes to the top of the screen in CSS?

Tags: css, animation

As I open my page, my text appears in the middle of the screen by an animation (I use “animate.css”) and then I want it to move to the top of the screen no matter what the screen size is. Is there a way to do that?

How I centered my text div;

```
.center {

        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 170px;
        background-color: red;

    }
```

My animation techniques; (instead of bottom: 300px, I want it to go to the top of the page.)

```
.center:hover {

        -webkit-animation: animationShrink 2s 1 ease forwards;

    }

    .container:hover {

        -webkit-animation: animationUp 2s 1 ease forwards;

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animationShrink {

        from {

            font-size: 1em;

        }
        to {

            font-size: 0.6em;

        }

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animationUp {

        from {

            bottom: 0px;

        } to {

            bottom: 300px;

        }

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: To the top of the screen of the top of the page? In the first case, use `fixed` positioning. Fiddle around with that, and create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddlen.net) if you can't get it done

Comment: Yes. I want it to go to the top of the page so my menu items can flow to the sides of it. But i want a smooth animation too. And i couldn’t really get what you mean by using fixed positioning. Where should i be using it?

Comment: Try `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`

Comment: I have edited the question may you have a look at it now?

Comment: have you tried to change `bottom` to `top`? ;) Please create a fiddle for us, it's much easier to help you then

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a class='center'>Text</a>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50vh - (170px / 2));
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: red;
    -ms-transition: top 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: top 1s linear;
    -o-transition: top 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s linear;
    transition: top 1s linear;

}

.center:active {
    top: 0;
    -ms-transition: top 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: top 2s linear;
    -o-transition: top 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s linear;
    transition: top 2s linear;
}
```

Check this plunker for example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GvH176vMGKSD47VrleXQ?p=preview

I used pseudo-class "active" to start animation (activate by clicking on element, just for example). This code should give you good base for customising.